# Error resolving cookbook

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, aws-opsworks, cookbook

I went through many similar threads but none answers my problem. I have [mysql 4.1.2 recipe](https://github.com/gitsubham/chef-repo.git). when i run it in opsworks i gives me this error. when i run the similar recipe in my local ubuntu it works fine. i have done some heavy tweaking with version number of dependencies, but still no solution. What can be the cause of this problem ?
My [CookBook repo](https://github.com/gitsubham/chef-repo.git) is at github

```
    ================================================================================
    Error Resolving Cookbooks for Run List:
    ================================================================================


    Missing Cookbooks:
    ------------------
    Could not satisfy version constraints for: mysql
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your version of the `database` cookbook requires [`mysql >= 5.0.0`](https://github.com/gitsubham/chef-repo/blob/b80d80a61a45f4f97bcf041b07e12889a2ad6630/database/metadata.rb#L15) but you have `4.1.2`.

Comment: please can you tell me how you came to know about that ? that will really help !

Comment: I searched your code for all lines like "depends 'mysql'" to find which constraints were unmet.

Comment: using grep ? what is the command .. i was using grep -rcl "depends \'mysql\' " but it didnt worked for me.

Comment: I just did it on github to avoid having to clone your repo locally. https://github.com/gitsubham/chef-repo/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=depends+mysql

Answer (score 5):

Another place to look is your environments file `cookbook_versions` properties. If a cookbook version is specified there, it could be conflicting with other version specifications.

https://docs.chef.io/environments.html

Comment: Hello my friend and saviour! This answer helps years into the future!
I always fall into this trap, when my deps are `>= 1.0`, and my env pinning is `= 1.1`. If a `1.2` exists, Berks will fetch that, but chef won't run because of env pinnings. Thanks!

Comment: I confirm, from the distant 2019, that this two comments from wisbucky and VladFr are something Chef should put in their docs. Very helpful indeed.

Answer (score 4):

Beside solution that @coderanger gave you, good practise to avoid issues like
this and escape dependency hell this is to use some kind of cookbook
manager (dependency manager for cookbooks).

There is a few options such [Berkshelf](http://berkshelf.com/) or 
[Librarian-chef](https://github.com/applicationsonline/librarian-chef),
where Berkshelf is more popular, and it's even included in 
[Chef Development Kit](https://downloads.getchef.com/chef-dk/), so if you use it
you do not need to install it separately.

So basically idea behind this is to have one place where you define your sorces
of all of your cookbooks, default one is [Chef Supermarket](https://supermarket.getchef.com/)
or if you you want you can use custom location or git repo as source.

After defining sources you just need to define which cookbooks you want (with or 
without) desired version or tag you want and cookbook manager will resolve 
dependencies for all defined cookbooks and it will install them for you,
and if you want you can vendor them too.

For more info how to use those tools consult official websites:

- http://berkshelf.com
- https://github.com/applicationsonline/librarian-chef

Comment: @ratasheep, i still have to mention the version of the dependency. and the problem i am having is with the versions of those dependencies. also , does berkshelf works when i use it with Aws - opsworks,  because i need to use it with that only.

Comment: If you use the latest OpsWorks stack, it includes support for Berkshelf.

Comment: ok. thanx .. but again the same question " i still have to mention the version of the dependency. and the problem i am having is with the versions of those dependencies. "

Comment: @coderanger, please clarify one more doubt for me. say for eg : i have a recipe A which depends on recipe B and recipe C. now this recipe B depends on recipe D and recipe C depends on recipe E. if i mention only recipe B and C on my berksfile, will it automatically manage recipe D and E. do i have to mention their names too in berksfile ?

Comment: @Subham Tripathi it automatically resolves dependencies, so you do not need to specify exact dependencies, only top level cookbooks. In this your example it's perfectly fine to add only recipe A and all it's dependencies  (cookbooks B, C, D and E) will be resolved and installed. And about version, if you do not need any specific version of top level cookbook, you do not need to specify version too, in that case Berkshelf will use the latest one.